# Spring can't created bean when class has $1.class

Tags: spring, exception, constructor, inversion-of-control

When I compiled my java's file,and java compiler generated extra class,like example.class,example$1.class,example$2.class in my package,

and My ApplicationContext's file to scan component like this.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test">
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="com\.test\..*"/>
```

then I got this error message.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'example.1' defined in file [/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8050-relayserver.war-_relayserver-any-2814616804903816631.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/test/example$1.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.test.example$1]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.example$1.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1040)
```

For now,I just only set exclude filter to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyClass$1 (and $2 and so on) classes are generated for **anonymous inner classes** in your class. Anonymous inner classes are commonly used when using the listener pattern, they are defined like this:

```java
MyInterface listener = new MyInterface() { // this is the anonymous inner class
  ... // implementation
}
```

So I guess you did try to use autowire on an anonymous inner class, which I suspect is not supported by spring (hard to say more without code).